# C# NHibernate - Remove all references to object on delete

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two objects.  One, the parent, references a Locale.  This locale is from a list of locales.  When that locale is deleted, I want it to clean up any references to itself from all referencing types (setting the relevant value to null).

Right now, I have a system that walks across all entities that NHibernate is mapping and, by using their class metadata, determines which types reference the locale type.  Then, I build a query (using ICriteria) for that referencing type where the property of type Locale equals the locale's Id that I'm trying to delete.  Any objects that come back, I set that property to null and then update them.

**Question**: Is there a better way - hopefully using something built into NHibernate - to instruct an object to remove all references to itself on delete?

**Objects:**

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Locale Loc { get; set; }
}

public class Locale
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Mappings:**

```
public class ParentMapping : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();

    References(x => x.Loc).Nullable();
}

public class LocaleMapping : ClassMap<Locale>
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
}
```

Comment: I think you're mapping is wrong.  Both are mapping to <Parent>.  Also the small p parent in this relationship is the Locale.  From your mappings, References is a many to one mapping, where Locale is the one.  Have you thought about making the mapping bi-directional back to the Locale?  Setting cascade on the relationship.

Comment: I apologize.  I knew I would make a typo somewhere.  I've corrected it.  It should be `LocaleMapping : ClassMap<Locale>`.  When you say bi-directional, you mean the locale entity knowing about all parents that have it, correct?

Comment: The reason I shy away from the locale entity knowing about all parents that have it is that it makes it difficult to then load only the Locale without all of that other information.  I want the locale to be as clean as possible.

Comment: Can you clarify "difficult to then load only the Locale?"   Are you loading the Locale to edit it in a screen?  Is there some other processing you are doing with Locale?  I tend to always use projections when getting information about a specific entity.  This ensures that you aren't loading entire object hierarchies when you only need a single entity.

Comment: @DanielAtwood, how did you solve the issue? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @ironstone13 The answer to that is a bit complicated, so I'll reply in an answer post, instead of a comment.  Thanks for asking!  It's nice to see that I'm not the only one that dealt with this.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, here's how I wound up dealing with this problem.  I actually used a suggestion originally given by @Fran to come up with a solution.

**Solution**

This solution is very specific to my type of application and involves using a number of parts of the application working together to achieve my desired result.  Specifically, my application is a RESTful web service, powered by WCF, JSON.NET, and NHibernate.

First, I added a reference to all parents in the locale and used a HasMany mapping, so that the locale knew all of the parents that reference it:

```
public virtual IList<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
```

and

```
HasMany(x => x.Parents);
```

It's also important to point out here that I use lazy loading throughout the application.

While this allowed me to easily delete the locale by using the proper cascade behaviors, this posed a problem in loading/GET scenarios in that when I passed the locale into JSON.NET (on its way out the door to the client), JSON.NET would walk the Parents collection, and serialize the whole thing.  Obviously, this is undesired as we're feeding the client much more than they asked for.  This is the problem I alluded to in my comment in the OP.

As @Fran mentioned, I could use projections; however, all of my reference lists are accessed through a common endpoint in order to abstract their CRUD operations and reduce the amount of repeated code: all of my reference lists implement an abstract class called ReferenceListBase.  Anyways, I wanted a solution in which the implementing class itself was able to decide how much of it should be sent to the client (serialized).

My solution was to put a [[JsonIgnore](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm)] attribute on the Parents collection, which, in conjuction with lazy loading, means that JSON.NET never looks at the property and therefore, the relationship never gets loaded.

This solution has always kind of felt like a hack, but it has achieved all of the results I want and made adding new reference lists very easy.  I hope this helps you; if it doesn't, post a new question, link it here, and I'll try to help you out. :)